# Correct use of variable argument functions C API with C++ implementation

Tags: c++, c, aws-sdk-cpp

I want to use a C++ logging library in a mixed C/C++ application. The legacy application is full of printf style logging. The new library also supports that.

The C files are compiled with C compiler, so I am not able to include C++ logging headers into them.

I am struggling to create a C++ library with C-style headers and C++ source file:

```
//logger.h
extern "C" {
    extern void RS_LOG_INFO_PRIVATE(const char* fmt, ...);
    #define LOG_INFO(...)  RS_LOG_INFO_PRIVATE(__VA_ARGS__)
}

//logger.cpp
#include "logger.h"
#include <aws/core/utils/logging/LogMacros.h>
#include <utility>
template<class... Args>
void RS_LOG_INFO_PRIVATE(const char* fmt, Args&&... args) {    
    AWS_LOG_DEBUG(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//main file
#include "logger.h"

int main() {
    LOG_INFO("test %s", "me");
}
```

I get `undefined reference to 'RS_LOG_INFO_PRIVATE'`.

`nm -C` also verifies this:

```
U RS_LOG_INFO_PRIVATE(char const*, ...)
```

Is there a solution to solve this, or I should change my approach?

Comment: `extern "C" void RS_LOG_INFO_PRIVATE(const char* fmt, ...);` and `template<class... Args>
void RS_LOG_INFO_PRIVATE(const char* fmt, Args&&... args)` are **not** the same.  C-style `...` varargs are **not** C++ `Args&&...`.

Comment: If you can avoid variadic functions then do so. They are one of the biggest design flaws of C and should never have been invented in the first place.

Comment: I sense a massive misunderstanding of C++ templates.. try reading this first: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @Lundin That's not likely to be feasible given "The legacy application is full of printf style logging."

Comment: In C, this ugliness is handled via the va_args hack, and C++ variadic templates have absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with that, and the two are two completely different and incompatible approaches, that work in fundamentally different ways. Stick to variadic templates for C++ and write a C-only hack that uses va_args.

Comment: @Lundin Nevermind in the first implementations of C all functions were *de facto* varargs where all function arguments always underwent default argument promotion, although I suspect that wasn't the term used originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are recompiling your application, you can seriously consider changing from a C compiler to a C++ compiler. Doing so will cause various compilation issues, but resolving them is usually no more difficult than some major modification to how C compilation was done (e.g., new compiler vendor, or increasing compiler warning levels). In this way, you may be able to avoid using C style variable arguments, and replace them with variadic template calls instead.

If switching to a C++ compiler is not viable, then you have to make your header files act as a C header file for the C compiler, and act as a C++ header file for the C++ compiler (or maintain two different header files for the different compilers).

Assuming your C and C++ compiler have compatible C ABIs, then the usual mechanism for detecting which compiler is being used is the `__cplusplus` macro.

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
// ... C++ stuff
#endif
```

One common trick is to make a C header file useable to a C++ header file by wrapping its contents with `extern "C"`. It seems you attempted to do this, but without the `__cplusplus` check.

```
#pragma once

/* A C header file made to work for C++ */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* rest C stuff ... */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

A C compiler will not understand what `extern "C"` is, hence it is hidden by the `__cplusplus` check, which would be defined for a C++ compiler.

The library implementation of the variable argument functions should not be different when implemented in C++ (`#include`ing the header file). The implementation would then call whatever C++ implementation code is required to actually complete what the call is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks. The catch word is which I didn't know is: `extern "C"` makes a function-name in C++ have C linkage; as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/805896